# Cant get json from the javascript to the java in play

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, playframework

```
 function check() {
    var svar = document.getElementsByName("svar");
    var len = svar.length;

    var object = 5;

    var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'http://localhost:9000/postasvar',
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        data : jsonData
    });
```

}

I got the above code in my javascript with the purpose to send a json object to the java.

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result postaSvar(){
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    //String svar = json.findPath("svar").textValue();
    if(json== null){
        return badRequest("förväntade json");
    }else{
        return ok("hello " + json);

    }

}
```

The java code above is the code that is suppose to handle the json from the javascript but the answer i get is always null.

I also have the following code in my main.scala.html:

```
    @(title: String)(content: Html)

     <!DOCTYPE html>

        <html>
          <head>
         <title>@title</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen"               href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/check.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/hello.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</head>
<body>
    @content
</body>
</html>
```

And this is index.scala.html:

```
       @(message: String)

        @main("Welcome to Play") {

@message

   <form action="http://localhost:9000/postasvar" method="post">
    </br>
    <input type="radio" name="svar"  value="svar1"/>svar1
    <input type="radio" name="svar"  value="svar2"/>svar2
    <input type="radio" name="svar"  value="svar3"/>svar3
    <input type="radio" name="svar"  value="svar4"/>svar4</br>
    <button name="knappen" onclick="check();">Klar</button>
   </form>


}
```

Is it someone who know what the problem might be?

Comment: JSON-stringifying something and then JSON-parsing it cannot be right.  Why don't you look at what is actually being posted and see if you are happy with that?

Comment: How can you see that?

Comment: Use the built-in debugger in your [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) or [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger) browser.  Basically, things went wrong _somewhere_: in check(), in the ajax call, in the webserver or in the Play function.  Track down where first, the what is usually easy.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help with that, solved some of my problems, but now have more occured. This time i get ajaxtransport error and extend error in the console, what might that be?

Comment: Again, try to split the problem.  Either the problem is, as Salem suggest, that your data is incorrect, or the problem is something else.  Instead of `data : jsonData`, try using `data : '{"svar":"svar1"}''` and see if that works.  Right now, you are setting it to the number 5, and that doesn't look right to me.

Comment: @cuecumber12 Without the error trace I would guess the problem is again with jQuery: as I said using `dataType : 'json'` you are telling jQuery you will receive JSON data back, but you are returning just simple text (`hello 4` for example). Do whatever suits you better: removing that or returning valid json.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to give a string to jQuery to send and not an object. In your case you get always null because jQuery is not sending anything in the body.

For example, if you do this

```
$.ajax({
    // (...)
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    data : {name: "Salem"}
});
```

jQuery will send this in the request body

```
name=Salem
```

and not the object formatted as JSON (`dataType` specifies the type of response it is waiting, not the type of data it is sending). So send a string instead:

```
$.ajax({
    // (...)
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify({name: "Salem"})
});
```

which will send the correct body and work as expected

```
{"name": "Salem"}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved some of my problems, but new have occured now as i mentioned in the comment of my post.